# Do real time project in hibernate need connection code or connection pooling to connect to database

Tags: hibernate, connection

Do real time project in hibernate need connection code or connection pooling to connect to database or hibernate.config.xml is enough?

Answer (score 0):

With Hibernate you do not need to write the connection code but you do need to configure your connection which Hibernate will use and generate the connection code for you.

Any real time project that does use Hibernate as the ORM tool will have to specify the connection properties. Also realtime projects would not reinvent the wheel but use ready made connection pools like c3po.

The below configuration willl help you understand

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
"-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN"
"http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-configuration>
<session-factory>
<property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver</property>
<property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:MKYONG</property>
 <property name="hibernate.connection.username">mkyong</property>
 <property name="hibernate.connection.password">password</property>
 <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect</property>
 <property name="hibernate.default_schema">MKYONG</property>
 <property name="show_sql">true</property>

 <property name="hibernate.c3p0.min_size">5</property>
 <property name="hibernate.c3p0.max_size">20</property>
 <property name="hibernate.c3p0.timeout">300</property>
 <property name="hibernate.c3p0.max_statements">50</property>
 <property name="hibernate.c3p0.idle_test_period">3000</property>

<mapping class="com.mkyong.user.DBUser"></mapping>
</session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

You can find the entire example at this link : http://www.mkyong.com/hibernate/how-to-configure-the-c3p0-connection-pool-in-hibernate/